# ImageonLoad directive AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a directive Imageonload to manage a preloader for my images loading :

Directive.js

```
  .directive('imageOnload', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                // call the function that was passed
                scope.$apply(attrs.imageOnload);
                // usage: <img ng-src="src" image-onload="imgLoadedCallback()" />
            });
        }
    };
  });
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.imgLoadedCallback=function(map){

      map.flag=false;

    };
```

Viewer.html

```
    <img  src="images/loading_bar.gif" ng-show="mapAllDataSets[$index].flag" >


<img   class="img-responsive center-block"  ng-src="{{mapAllDataSets[$index].src}}" image-onload="imgLoadedCallback(mapAllDataSets[$index])" >
```

It's working fine as long as i don't try to display the same image again in a row.

If i call the same image my preloader won't hide . I don't understand why .

Comment: Could you make a (basic, simple) plunker or fiddle and post the link? It will be easier to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Because of image caching the 'onload' event could not fire, so you could try to add the following lines to your code:

```
if (element[0].complete) {
  element[0].load();
}
```

This code checks if the image is already loaded and triggers *manually* the onload event.

Here is a code example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $log) {

  $scope.imgLoadedCallback = function(map) {
    $log.info('imgLoadedCallback');
    map.flag = false;
  };

  $scope.mapAllDataSets = [
    {flag: true, src: "http://www.download-free-wallpaper.com/img10/paluegqweqrschoxqqtx.jpg"},
    {flag: true, src: "http://www.download-free-wallpaper.com/img42/xfokptpwjejkiqsmcatc.jpg"},
    {flag: true, src: "http://desktop-backgrounds-org.s3.amazonaws.com/free-desktop-high-definition.jpg"},
    {flag: true, src: "http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Butterfly-Free-Wallpaper-For-Desktop.jpg"},
    {flag: true, src: "http://theartmad.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Nice-Wallpapers-For-Desktop-Free-Download-2.jpg"},
    {flag: true, src: "http://www.download-free-wallpaper.com/img10/paluegqweqrschoxqqtx.jpg"},
    {flag: true, src: "http://www.download-free-wallpaper.com/img42/xfokptpwjejkiqsmcatc.jpg"},
    {flag: true, src: "http://desktop-backgrounds-org.s3.amazonaws.com/free-desktop-high-definition.jpg"},
    {flag: true, src: "http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Butterfly-Free-Wallpaper-For-Desktop.jpg"},
    {flag: true, src: "http://theartmad.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Nice-Wallpapers-For-Desktop-Free-Download-2.jpg"},
    ];

})

.directive('imageOnload', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('load', function() {
        // call the function that was passed
        scope.$apply(attrs.imageOnload);
        // usage: <img ng-src="src" image-onload="imgLoadedCallback()" />
      });
      if (element[0].complete) {
        element[0].load();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>AngularJS: load directive</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="map in mapAllDataSets">
      <img  class="center-block" src="http://www.onlinedesignteacher.com/images/loadingbar.gif" ng-show="map.flag" >
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" 
      ng-src="{{map.src}}"
      image-onload="imgLoadedCallback(mapAllDataSets[$index])">
      <p>picture {{$index}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>mapAllDataSets = {{mapAllDataSets | json}}</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, i have done something like : 

// test if the new image.src is different from the actual image src and then depending on this condition i hide or show the preloader .

i'm sure that there's a better solution for this more angularjs like solution

Comment: Sorry :(. Maybe there is some problem in another part of your code that you didn't share